# meteor with flow-router: Do I have access to Meteor.User from within a flow-router trigger?

Tags: javascript, meteor, flow-router

I believe that from **security perspective**, it is best to handle access to restricted URL in 2 places:

- **Routing level**: Make sure no-one will be able to get to a route which is not permitted for
- **Template level**: No restricted data will be showed before verifying permissions.

`Iron-Router` support the first way, but I want to use `Flow-Router`.

I found an article by `Satya van He-men`, [Meteor: Using Flow Router for authentication and permissions](https://medium.com/@satyavh/using-flow-router-for-authentication-ba7bb2644f42#.cxoobuixj)
In This article he is using routing groups and triggers to "filter" routes by permissions.
But in this article he is using 
`Meteor.loggingIn()`, `Meteor.userId()`, `Meteor.user()` and `Roles.userIsInRole()` **inside the `triggersEnter:`** function of the `FlowRouter` object.

---

Is it possible that any of those functions will be **undefined** during the **`triggersEnter`** execution?
**Is it safe to use them?**
I like the pattern from the article, but want to make sure it is safe to use (or can become safe with few changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your reason for concern is valid it's possible because `triggersEnter` called just once I recommend reading the official tutorial on the Auth Logic Permission which is on the Template level and it's reactive.

> Previously, we did this in the router layer (specifically with Iron
>   Router). However, that's not a good design and we don't recommend it.

https://kadira.io/academy/meteor-routing-guide/content/implementing-auth-logic-and-permissions

Comment: Thanks @Mark, I went through those documents before, but hope that there is a safe way to do it in the router level anyway.  
This is because from security perspective, it is best to stop the user before the gate and not inside...

Comment: @lzack yeah but the problem is we do not have server side rendering this might change the way we do auth on route level, But this is actually very safe! Even if you bypass the template level checks the only thing you do is change the UI. The user will never get unauthorized access if you do your security check properly on `publishing` functions so if there is no data nothing is exposed :)

Comment: thanks again. I know I can(and should) secure on data level and template level. but adding route level improve it (It can hide "secure" URLs and be a front line defence in case we had "bug" in any of the other levels)  
 Just as a thought: if I will call the routing.js file `main.routes.js`, wouldn't it be loaded after the other objects already exist?

Answer (score 1):

I also noted that `Roles.userIsInRole()` as well as other security related functions can return `undefined` in the `triggerEnter` function. Since I also noticed that [the article you mentioned](https://medium.com/@satyavh/using-flow-router-for-authentication-ba7bb2644f42#.t8nsei7ff) is using them without issues, it led me to investigate.

Here is why, as far as I can tell: if you use a container, you need to make sure that the user is not currently logging in at this level before loading any template in the field (and thus trigger the route enter function with no `Meteor.userId()`.

So you can use all user rights related functions in `triggerEnter` as long as you do something like this in your container, basically preventing any template from being loaded as long as the user is logging in:

```
  {{#if authInProcess}}
    <p>loading ...</p>
  {{else}}
    {{> Template.dynamic template=layout}} // load your template
  {{/if}}
```

with an helper looking like that:

```
authInProcess: function() {
    return Meteor.loggingIn();
  },
```

Note that this code is taken from there: https://kadira.io/academy/meteor-routing-guide/content/implementing-auth-logic-and-permissions